# Why is Heroku giving me an H10 error when I deploy Django app

Tags: django, heroku-postgres

Hi all first time deploying an app and working with django. it keeps giving me the error code H10. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here are my files. I'm not sure what to do i've tried so many guides and tutorials and followed the documentation.
If anyone could give me some guidance and let me know if they see anything obvious that wrong it would be greatly appreciated!

`Procfile`

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

`Requirements.txt`

```
asgiref==3.3.1
astroid==2.4.2
colorama==0.4.4
Django==3.1.3
django-crispy-forms==1.10.0
django-mysql==3.9.0
djangorestframework==3.12.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
isort==5.6.4
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
mysql-connector-python==8.0.21
mysqlclient==2.0.1
pylint==2.6.0
pytz==2020.4
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
toml==0.10.2
whitenoise==5.2.0
wrapt==1.12.1
```

`settings.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '***'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = false

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myrecipebook1.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1']

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.Custom_User'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'users',
    'recipe',
    'django_mysql',
    'drf_yasg',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    #S'pillow',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

SWAGGER_SETTINGS={
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS' : {
        'Bearer':
        {
            'type' : 'apiKey',
            'name' : 'Authorization',
            'in' : 'header'
        }
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'RecipeApp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'RecipeApp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : '***', 
        'USER' : '***',
        'PASSWORD' : '***',
        'HOST' : 'localHost',
        'PORT' : '3306',
    }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()

DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "staticfiles")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
   # 'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
      #  'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
   # ]
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=1),
}

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: Do not add your secret Key here. You should change it now same goes for your db password. A H10 usually means your app crashed, please post the error log